# SVG issue : using values and calcmode

Tags: svg, svg-animate, smil

I'm learning how to animate svg.

I can animate between two shapes with calcMode="spline", I can animate between three shapes without calcMode="spline", but I can't animate between three shapes with calcMode="spline".

Here's my example :

```
<animate
        attributeName="d"   
        attributeType="XML"     
        begin="0"               
        from="M662.1,170.5c-0.2,0-0.3-0.1-0.4-0.3l-3.5-7.9c-0.1-0.2,1-0.1,1-0.1l3.2,7.7c0.1,0.2,0,0.5-0.2,0.6
        C662.2,170.5,662.1,170.5,662.1,170.5z"

        to="M704,146.5c-0.6,0-1.1-0.3-1.4-0.9l-12.4-28.1c-0.3-0.7,3.6-0.5,3.6-0.5l11.6,27.4c0.3,0.8,0,1.6-0.8,2
        C704.4,146.4,704.2,146.5,704,146.5z"
        dur="2s"
        values="
        M662.1,170.5c-0.2,0-0.3-0.1-0.4-0.3l-3.5-7.9c-0.1-0.2,1-0.1,1-0.1l3.2,7.7c0.1,0.2,0,0.5-0.2,0.6
        C662.2,170.5,662.1,170.5,662.1,170.5z;
        M704,146.5c-0.6,0-1.1-0.3-1.4-0.9l-16.4-25.1c-0.3-0.7,3.6-0.5,3.6-0.5l15.6,24.4
        c0.3,0.8,0,1.6-0.8,2C704.4,146.4,704.2,146.5,704,146.5z;
        M704,146.5c-0.6,0-1.1-0.3-1.4-0.9l-12.4-28.1c-0.3-0.7,3.6-0.5,3.6-0.5l11.6,27.4c0.3,0.8,0,1.6-0.8,2
        C704.4,146.4,704.2,146.5,704,146.5z"

        calcMode      = "spline"
        keySplines    = "0 0.75 0.25 1"
        keyTimes      = "0;1;2"
        />
```

If I remove values an adjust keyTimes="0;1", it works.
If I remove calcMode, keySplines and keyTimes, it works.
But it doesn't work together.
Did I made a mistake somewhere, or can't we use both together?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the SVG Specification:

> the ‘[keySplines](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/animate.html#KeySplinesAttribute)’ values are the control points. Thus, there must be one fewer sets of control points than there are ‘keyTimes’.

You've one keySplines value so you need 2 keyTimes values. Alternatively, you need to have 2 keySplines values in order to support 3 keyTimes values.

Comment: Slight mix-up: one set of splines = two times (the basic situation that was working).  For three `keyTimes` and `values`, you'd need two sets of splines, like `keySplines="0 0.75 0.25 1; 0 0.75 0.25 1"`.

Comment: Apparently I can't add up or subtract or something. Answer corrected.